I can not login via using Spring Security form login
I am trying to implement form login using spring security and a custom login page. But I am getting LazyInitializationException during login.
2024-12-01T22:04:46.534+03:00  WARN 18068 --- [PasswordManager] [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=2m8s163ms940µs900ns).
2024-12-01T22:04:46.542+03:00 ERROR 18068 --- [PasswordManager] [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/oauth/v1] threw exception

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.batuhankertmen.oauthserver.user.User.roles: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:634) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1959) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:414) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:508) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.batuhankertmen.oauthserver.user.User.getAuthorities(User.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:197) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:141) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:168) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


My User implentation
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="users")
@Transactional
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private boolean enabled;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String contact;

    private Date createdAt;

    private Date lastUpdatedAt;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<Authority> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAuthority()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<AuthorizationCode> authorizationCodes = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "allowed_client",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    )
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<Client> allowedClients = new HashSet<>();

    public void addAllowedClient(Client client) {
        allowedClients.add(client);
        client.getUsers().add(this);
    }

    public void removeAllowedClient(Client client) {
        allowedClients.remove(client);
        client.getUsers().remove(this);
    }

    public void addAuthority(Authority authority) {
        roles.add(authority);
        authority.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeAuthority(Authority authority) {
        roles.remove(authority);
        authority.setUser(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
}

This exception is occuring when spring is trying to reach getAuthorites() method. When I look at it with a debugger I can see that all of the child entities are giving same exception as can be seen from the picture below.

All of the separete entites are giving the same error. When I searched from the internet it said this could be due to entities fetch type being lazy but they are eager in my code. Also in the internet they were talking about it not being transaction but my user class has transactional annotation at the beginning. I am also adding my Authorities class for conveniance.
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "authority")
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "ROLE_" + role.name();
    }
}

I also checked if this is a recurring problem in other parts of my code or is it only during spring security login and I found out everything is working out as expected. During the registration process I used debugger to see if I can reach my user instances can access and they can as it can be seen in the picture below.

Clearly connections are working as expected in my code but for some reason when springsecurity is trying to authenticate users it can not access them.
I am not sure if my spring security config is needed so I am adding it too and my loginProcessingUrl is allowed.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final AuthenticationProvider userAuthProvider;
    private final AuthenticationProvider companyAuthProvider;

    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userAuthProvider") AuthenticationProvider userAuthProvider,
                          @Qualifier("companyAuthProvider") AuthenticationProvider companyAuthProvider) {
        this.userAuthProvider = userAuthProvider;
        this.companyAuthProvider = companyAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain userSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                //.securityMatcher("/client/permission", "/client/authorize", "/user/allow")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/client/permission").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/client/authorize").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/allow").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .authenticationProvider(userAuthProvider)
                .headers( headers -> headers
                        .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .formLogin( form -> form
                        .loginPage("/auth/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/perform_login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                        .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                        .failureUrl("/auth/login?error")
                        .permitAll());

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}

I do not now what do or what to search for anymore so any help is appreciated.

you post a bunch of code, but you dont read your own stacktrace and see that the problem is here org.batuhankertmen.oauthserver.user.User.getAuthorities and you also dont post that code for us to read?

@Toerktumlare Yes I read my own stack trace and getAuthorities code is there in the first code block. Also it is just trying to reach Authority list as showed in the picture but it is failing due to reasons I shared.

they are eager in my code no they are not, all relationships OneToMany, ManyToMany, OneToOne are all Lazy By default

@Toerktumlare Oh thank you. I assumed the default behaviour was eager due to it being eager in the opposite direction. This solved the error.

All relationship annotations in hibernate like OneToMany, ManyToMany, OneToOne are LAZY by default.
Which means they will not be fetched until you explicitly use one of the values.
If you wish to change this you can set for instance @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) in the annotation.
You can use some ugly tricks by calling size on the collection to force hibernate to fetch the values.

You can also annotate method reaching for this object as @Transactional
